# How to make component reload automatically after state changes?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, state

In a component, I have a function which allows to create gardens and in another component I have a function which allows to recover these gardens which have just been created. But when I go to the screen of this component, I have to reload my application myself to see the gardens that I have just created, this is not done automatically. How can I do so that once the garden creates my GET request retrieves it automatically?

Here is my component that creates the garden:

```js
export default function FormCreateGarden({navigation}) {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [garden, setGarden] = useState(false);
  const [gardenName, setGardenName] = useState('');
  const [gardenImage, setGardenImage] = useState({uri: '', type: '', name: ''});
  const [isVisible, setIsVisible] = useState(false);

  const baseUrl = 'http://127.0.0.1/api';

  const submitButton = async () => {
    if (!gardenName.trim()) {
      alert("Veuillez renter un nom de jardin s'il vous plait!");
      return;
    }
    setLoading(true);
    try {
      const jsonValue = await AsyncStorage.getItem('user');
      const parsedUserData = JSON.parse(jsonValue) || {};
      setUser(parsedUserData);

      const myHeaders = new Headers();
      myHeaders.append('Authorization', `Token ${parsedUserData.token}`);

      const photo = {
        uri: gardenImage.uri,
        type: gardenImage.type,
        name: gardenImage.name,
      };

      const formdata = new FormData();
      formdata.append('name', gardenName);
      formdata.append('user', parsedUserData.user.id);
      formdata.append('image', photo);

      const requestOptions = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: myHeaders,
        body: formdata,
        redirect: 'follow',
      };

      const response = await fetch(`${baseUrl}/garden/`, requestOptions);

      if (response.status === 201) {
        let data = await response.json();
        alert(`Votre jardin "${gardenName}" a bien été crée`);
        
        setLoading(false);
        setGardenName('');
        setGardenImage({uri: '', type: '', name: ''});
        
        navigation.navigate('GardenHome');
      } else {
        throw new Error('Erreur');
      }
    } catch (e) {
      setLoading(false);
      console.log(e.message);
      console.log(e);
    }
  };

  return (
        <View
          style={{
            backgroundColor: '#32493c',
            paddingLeft: 5,
            paddingRight: 5,
            marginLeft: 20,
          }}>
          <Button
            title="Valider"
            color={'white'}
            onPress={submitButton}
          />
        </View>
  );
}
```

Here is my component that retrieves the created gardens:

```js
export default function GardenHome() {
  const [garden, setGarden] = useState([]);
  const [plot, setPlot] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const navigation = useNavigation();

  const gardenData = async () => {
    setLoading(true);
    const user = await AsyncStorage.getItem('user');
    const parsedUserData = JSON.parse(user);
    try {
      const response = await axios.get(
        `http://127.0.0.1/api/garden?user=${parsedUserData.user.id}`,
        {
          headers: {
            Authorization: `Token ${parsedUserData.token}`,
          },
        },
      );
      if (response.status === 200) {
        setGarden(response.data);
        setLoading(false);
      }
    } catch (e) {
      console.log('Erreur ' + e);
      setLoading(false);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    gardenData();
  }, []);
  
}
```

Comment: Component should reload automatically after setState. And this is what you are doing. But in your GardenHome I see no FormCreateGarden.

Comment: @lmasneri Thank you for your reply. `FormCreateGarden` is a separate screen in my application, it's where you create your garden. And in `GardenHome` it is where we find his gardens created. But when creating the gardens if the status is `201`, it redirects us to the GardenHome screen. But I have to reload the application myself to see the gardens created because it does not automatically...

Comment: Oh, I see. In your FormCreateGarden Response, the correct code should be 200 (when created without errors). And if you are in the response.status === 200 than you do something: The something you are looking for is react effector (https://effector.dev) or react redux (https://react-redux.js.org). Or you can simply remove your `[]` in your `useEffect` but it will be reloaded every time something change on your `GardenHome` screen.

Comment: @lmasneri Alright, thank you very much, I'll take a look there!

Comment: Let me know if it worked. If not just tag me under this comment and I will take a look.

Comment: @lmasneri It's good, I implemented Redux Toolkit in my application and everything works as I wanted, thank you!

Comment: Nice, happy that I can help :)